# Importing and plotting custom vector images in R

Tags: r

I wonder if there is any way to embed a user-specified vector image file such `.ai`, `.eps` or `.pdf` into an `R` plot, and allows you to place the file at any location you specified with custom scale and rotation settings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/vignettes/import.pdf for some ideas

Comment: Agree w/ thelatemail. Pretty much anything by Murrell can be considered R canon.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!